# Locally building and pushing VuePress site to Github Pages

Tags: github, github-pages, vuepress

Having trouble figuring out how the workflow for using Github as a VuePress site source control and [deploying it to Github Pages](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/deploy.html#github-pages).

When I ran `deploy.sh` the first time, it gave me a Github certificate error around the `init` command and did not initialize a new repo (I already have a repo setup so not sure if the `init` command in `deploy.sh` is required. Subsequent runs of `deploy.sh` resulted in no error.

**Problem:**Unfortunately, when I visit [my Github Pages site](https://seadude.github.io/powerDocs/), its not using VuePress templates.

**I feel like I have either:**
- The folder structure wrong
- The `base` set incorrectly in `config.js`
- The relative folders incorrect in `deploy.sh`

Can someone put eyes on this and give some feedback? Thank you.

**For your reference**

**Local machine's folder structure:**

```
user@system:~/powerDocs$ tree
.
├── deploy.sh
├── docs
│   └── README.md
├── node_modules
│   └── yarn
│       ├── bin
│       │   ├── yarn
│       │   ├── yarn.cmd
│       │   ├── yarn.js
│       │   ├── yarnpkg
│       │   └── yarnpkg.cmd
│       ├── lib
│       │   ├── cli.js
│       │   └── v8-compile-cache.js
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── package.json
│       └── README.md
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── README.md

5 directories, 15 files
```

**Content of `deploy.sh`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# abort on errors
set -e

# build
vuepress build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd docs/.vuepress/dist

# if you are deploying to a custom domain
# echo 'www.example.com' > CNAME

git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io
# git push -f git@github.com:SeaDude/SeaDude.github.io.git master

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>
git push -f git@github.com:SeaDude/powerDocs.git master:gh-pages

cd -
```

I made deploy.sh executable with `chmod +x deploy.sh`. Running `./deploy.sh` gives me the following output:

```
user@system:~/powerDocs$ ./deploy.sh 

 WAIT  Extracting site metadata...
[12:05:53 PM] Compiling Client
[12:05:53 PM] Compiling Server
(node:15590) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
[12:05:57 PM] Compiled Server in 3s
[12:05:59 PM] Compiled Client in 6s
 WAIT  Rendering static HTML...

 DONE  Success! Generated static files in .vuepress/dist.

Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/powerDocs/docs/.vuepress/dist/.git/
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**Here is the contents of `config.js`:**

```
module.exports = {
  title: "PowerDocs",
  description: "Where functions go to frolic.",
  base: "/powerDocs/",

  themeConfig: {
    nav: [
      { text: "Home", link: "/" }
    ],
    sidebar: [
      '/'
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your `dist` folder to see what is actually being output? The error makes it seem like there are no files present to commit after the build.

I have the almost identical setup locally and haven't run into this problem with it, the only difference being the command I run to build is `yarn docs:build`

Comment: Hi Sam. Pardon the extremely late response! Yes, the `dist` folder contains an `assets` folder, an `index.html` and `404.html` file.
But as you can see in the link, https://seadude.github.io/powerDocs/,  the generated site is not using the VuePress template. 
Any other thoughts?